# How can I run a Java app on Apache 2.2 without Tomcat?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

I'm building a webservice with Java that does not use JSP or servlets, and want to run it on my Apache HTTP server without having to install and configure Tomcat.  Is this possible (easily), and how can I go about it?

I've been searching for information on this and the only thing I've come across is the mod_jk Tomcat connector which still requires Tomcat to be installed.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I find it pretty unlikely that you're building a web-anything in Java without servlets, so the answer is almost certainly no. If you can explain how you're not using servlets, then there may be an answer for you.

Comment: What apache is used for is for either a) providing static content (images, sounds, etc.) and b) load balancing, since it is faster than Tomcat. But this is done *in coordination* with the Tomcat that serves the java-generated content.

Comment: Yes you can, if you want to reinvent the wheel and do what Tomcat already do. _Is this possible (easily)_ more easily than installing and configuring Tomcat, no.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, Servlets is the very basics of Java for Web development. So, whatever web development you are doing, like Web Services, you'll need a Servlet Container, as Tomcat.

So the answer to your question is "you cant run it's only on Apache HTTP Server", because it's not a Servlet Container.

Answer (score 19):

Of course It is possible. You could do It using mod_cgi.

A very simple example would be like this:

```
public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello Java CGI world!");
    }
}
```

and then a script file (HelloWorld.shtml -do not forget the execute permission) that executes the Java class

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""

/usr/bin/java HelloWorld
```

In Apache conf, just define your script directory, something like this:

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /Users/hectorsuarez/Proyectos/test/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/Users/hectorsuarez/Proyectos/test/cgi-bin">
    SetHandler cgi-script
    Options ExecCGI
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

That's it!. This is a very simple and trivial example.

This will get complicated because you could probably  need a template engine and a much better way to manage the incoming CGI calls. But yes, It is possible.

Comment: Avoiding doing this in Perl is why servlets (and servlet containers) were invented in the first place (by "in the first place", I mean the 1990's). This will not scale.

Answer (score 5):

It is not entirely clear what you want to do, but I'm going to guess that you want to run a stand-alone Java app which can handle HTTP requests and expose it via Apache.  If that's the case, you can do it by configuring Apache with mod_proxy.  [This](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Using+Apache+with+mod_proxy) might be a decent example of how this could be done.

Answer (score 0):

No, Tomcat, jetty, jboss or Glassfish is pretty much mandatory